# Does Oracle's Java 7 for Mac OS X have com.apple.eawt.CocoaComponent or similar?

Tags: java, macos, cocoa

Apple's Java, which is on version 6 on my machine, has a class `com.apple.eawt.CocoaComponent` for connecting AWT/Swing apps to Cocoa components.  An example use: displaying the UI of an AudioUnit (which is a Cocoa view) in a Java app.  I'd like to use Java 7, but I can't find this class in it.  Anyone know if it's there, somewhere?  Or if there is an alternative?

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution for that? I've also some classes extending CocoaComponent which fail on Java 7.

Comment: No solution yet. This project is on the back burner for a bit, and I haven't been working on it.

Comment: Hm. All I've found is this on the JDK OSX-Port status page: "Use CALayer-based JAWT embedding instead of CocoaComponent". So you have to implement your own native windows. I tell you if I've some working code.

Answer (score 2):

The `com.apple.eawt` classes are indeed included with the Oracle JDKs from 7u4 up through the latest (as of 10/30/2012) 7u9.  For some example usage, see [Fullscreen feature for Java Apps on OSX Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873568/fullscreen-feature-for-java-apps-on-osx-lion) or [FullScreen Swing Components Fail to Receive Keyboard Input on Java 7 on Mac OS X Mountain Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064607/fullscreen-swing-components-fail-to-receive-keyboard-input-on-java-7-on-mac-os-x)

One issue is that [they do not seem to be building javadoc for those classes at the moment](http://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2012/Aug/msg00112.html), so looking up the latest APIs is fairly difficult.  I've resorted to searching for the .java files online.  You may also have some luck with the older [API reference on developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Reference/JavaSE6_AppleExtensionsRef/api/index.html), though this does not include newer classes like FullScreenUtilities.

Comment: Okay, I just installed 7u10 on my Macbook. The rt.jar does have classes in the com.apple.eawt package, but no `CocoaComponent`, which is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are at Marven repo for eg, you can pull it: [here](http://mavenhub.com/c/com/apple/eawt/CocoaComponent/jar)

Hope it helps

Comment: I can find the classes there, or in a few other places, but if I try to run the app in Java 7, the Cocoa view is never created and I get exceptions in CocoaComponent.paint.  These Apple classes seem to be incompatible with the Java 7 VM from Oracle.