# Open Mac fullscreen out of java application

Tags: java, macos, swing, fullscreen

my Java application is able to use fullscreen mode with mac thanks to this code:

```
Class util = Class.forName("com.apple.eawt.FullScreenUtilities");
Class params[] = new Class[]{Window.class, Boolean.TYPE};
Method method = util.getMethod("setWindowCanFullScreen", params);
method.invoke(util, myJFrame, true);
```

But this only **enables** fullscreen button at the right upper corner. Is it possible **to go to fullscreen mode** out of the application, as example by JButton-click?

It's only relevant for Mac OS X.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fullscreen feature for Java Apps on OSX Lion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873568/fullscreen-feature-for-java-apps-on-osx-lion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using OS X (10.7 and higher), you can use the native fullscreen mode. Use this method to request the window go on full screen mod :

```
com.apple.eawt.Application.getApplication().requestToggleFullScreen(window);
```

Where `window` is your `JFrame` for example.

**EDIT :**
You can also see the [example](https://gist.github.com/dohpaz42/4200907) given by @trashgod in his comment.